# iOS crashes on init method of MFMailComposeViewController and SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, crash, unrecognized-selector

I am developing an iOS app with deployment target 7.0 and I'm trying to present built-in view controllers like MFMailComposeViewController and SKStoreProductViewController within the app. However, my app crashes as soon as I initialise any of the built-in view controllers with the following error message:

```
[__NSGlobalBlock__ encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x57986c
```

The crash occurs in the following lines:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

and

```
SKStoreProductViewController *storeViewController = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
```

I couldn't find any clue where this error comes from. I am using some third-party pods like KeepLayout and ReactiveCocoa that include some categories on UIView elements. Not sure if that is the source of this problem.

Here is the stack trace of crash caused by [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x103c0d47d __exceptionPreprocess + 141
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x10396c99e objc_exception_throw + 43
2 CoreFoundation 0x103c9e65d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3 CoreFoundation 0x103bfed8d ___forwarding___ + 973
4 CoreFoundation 0x103bfe938 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5 Foundation 0x101af43ef _encodeObject + 1150
6 Foundation 0x101af770f +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 162
7 UIKit 0x102cb841c -[_UIAppearanceRecorder _recordInvocation:withClassName:containerClassNames:selectorString:forRemoteProcess:] + 2450
8 UIKit 0x102cb3ff1 __54+[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:]_block_invoke + 838
9 CoreFoundation 0x103c8c10f __65-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 111
10 CoreFoundation 0x103c8c01e -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 206
11 UIKit 0x102cb3c99 +[_UIAppearance _recordersExcludingSource:withWindow:] + 137
12 UIKit 0x102e20c9c UIViewServiceCurrentAppearanceSerializedRepresentations + 77
13 UIKit 0x102d58038 +[_UIRemoteViewController requestViewController:fromServiceWithBundleIdentifier:connectionHandler:] + 197
14 Social 0x102626410 -[SLComposeViewController loadServiceViewControllerWithClassName:fromServiceBundleWithIdentifier:] + 172
15 Social 0x102623ec6 -[SLComposeViewController initWithServiceViewControllerClassName:hostingBundleIdentifer:] + 126
16 Social 0x102623d71 -[SLComposeViewController initWithServiceType:] + 267
17 Social 0x102624130 +[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:] + 65
```

Comment: A typical reason for this error is when you try to archive an object that doesn't implement NSCoding.  Neither built-in vc would do that.  Do you do any archiving, or maybe the 3rd party libs you use?

Comment: I don't see any reason for archiving in any of these VC init methods. How can I figure this out?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you should archive, but that somewhere you're code *is* trying to archive a block (which it shouldn't).  Try global search in your project for "encode" (use containing match).

Comment: @danh Alright, but how can this happen in the init method of a built-in VC?

Comment: The problem will be due to something else... it just seems to manifest there.  Try substituting UIViewController aloc-init.  I'll bet you'll see it then, too.

Comment: @danh I replaced it with [[UIViewController alloc] init] and it worked fine. I'll add the stack trace to the question. Maybe that gives more clue..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the MessageUI and StoreKit frameworks to your project. (In your Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries)

Comment: They are already included in the build phase and in the header of my Objective-C file. And I still get this error.

Comment: @Peyman are you configuring UIAppearance anywhere with an NSDictionary?

Comment: Not that I know of. The only usage of UIAppearance in my code is in BButton and SVProgressHUD 3rd-party cococa controls.